How similar do effect sizes (Odds Ratios) be to pool them in a meta-analysis?
I am currently working on a meta-analysis on the effect of household income on depression. An optimal primary study to be included would measure participants household income and depression at baseline, would then divide the sample into quantiles (e.g. quartiles) based on their income level, and would lastly measure depression incidence at follow-up to report how many participants from each income quantile suffered from depression from baseline to follow-up. This would give me the chance to determine odds ratios or risk ratios for the comparison of the depression incidence, e.g., the lowest compared to the highest income quantile. A good example for a study like this was conducted by Sareen et al. (2011): Relationship Between Household Income and Mental Disorders
Findings From a Population-Based Longitudinal Study.
However, as you can imagine, there is huge heterogeneity in the way primary studies on the matter are conducted. My biggest problems are that studies either use different sizes of quantiles for their comparisons, or combine quantiles in their comparisons (e.g., comparing depression incidence in the lowest income quantile to all higher quantiles), or use logistic regression models for which it is not transparent at all what coding was used for the comparisons. This opens the question of whether there is any sensible way to pool these effect sizes or if the way the ORs in the primary studies are conducted have to be very similar. Like, does it make any sense to both include ORs from a study using a logistic regression model to determine the odds ratio of income divided into sextiles on depression while controlling for covariates as well as a study that determined crude ORs based on the number of people in the lowest income quartile with that developed depression compared to the number of people in the highest income quartile?
Also, many studies do not investigate depression incidence but specify the effect of baseline income on depression prevalence at follow-up (thus, not excluding people with depression at baseline). Could those effects still be pooled or investigated in subgroup analyses?

There are measures for this. Probably the most common is $I^2$.  Have you looked at this? Have you looked at any references on metal analysis? They all cover this in some detail.

@PeterFlom thank you for your fast reply! Yes, I know about measures of heterogeneity. My uncertainty relates more to the content dimension: Are studies that compare, e.g., the lowest income category with the highest income category and those that compare the lowest income category with the middle income category comparable contentwise and can they be meaningfully pooled into one effect? Or is it sufficient that the predictor and criterion variable are the same across studies and that further deviations in the analysis can be accounted for using heterogeneity measures?

See also this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/371917/is-meta-analysis-of-odds-ratios-essentially-hopeless

To answer the simplest question first I do not think there is any sensible way to compare studies which measures incidence with studies which measured prevalence ignoring baseline.
You speak throughout of pooling but that need not be the point of meta-analysis. It is often sensible to use it to explore and explain differences between studies. In that context if studies have used different definitions of the exposure then you can include them all and use a moderator in a meta-regression.

In your comment you ask about cases where the comparisons are different, e.g. one study compares lowest income to highest, the other compares middle to highest.  If you have the full table, you can redo the odds ratios, but I don't see a way to combine them with just the information you state.
Even if the ODs were similar, they shouldn't be combined, because, in a way, similar ORs in these two situations would be indicative of different effect sizes.
Fortunately, a lot of studies do report all levels, and the calculations aren't hard.
